# to be assassinated or assassinated?

Tags: grammaticality

Can I use "**assassinated**" instead of "**to be assassinated**" in this sentence: "John F.Kennedy was the last US president **to be assassinated**"?

Comment: You mean, is the sentence, "*John F. Kennedy was the last US president **assassinated***" grammatical? Yes, it is. Though more natural would be, "*John F. Kennedy was the last **assassinated** US president.*"

Comment: @gotube - I might be inclined to use the 'historical present' and say that 'John F. Kennedy is the last assassinated US president'. Without wishing to be morbid, 'was' is rather final.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you.